# Running code from a custom AppDomain

Tags: c#, appdomain

I have the following plugin:

IPlugin.cs:

```
namespace StandalonePlugin
{
    public interface IPlugin
    {
        string Execute(string data);
    }
}
```

StandalonePlugin.cs:

```
namespace StandalonePlugin
{
    [Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
    public class StandalonePlugin : IPlugin
    {
        public string Execute(string data)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            result.AppendFormat("Plugintype: {0}\r\n", this.GetType().FullName);
            result.AppendFormat("Data: {0}\r\n", data);
            result.AppendFormat("AppDomain: {0}\r\n", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
            result.AppendFormat("Current Dir: {0}\r\n", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
            result.AppendFormat("Assembly location: {0}\r\n", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the code loading the plugin and calling it's Execute method:

```
namespace CustomAppDomain
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
            setup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            setup.PrivateBinPath = @".";

            AppDomain pluginDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("PluginDomain", null, setup);

            string pathToDll = @"D:\Code\LearningPlugins\StandalonePlugin\bin\Debug";
            Type t = typeof(IPlugin);
            IPlugin plugin = (IPlugin)pluginDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToDll, t.FullName);

            Console.WriteLine(plugin.Execute("Test"));

            Console.WriteLine("<ENTER> to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
> Plugintype: StandalonePlugin.StandalonePlugin 
> Data: Test 
> AppDomain:LearningPlugins.vshost.exe 
> Current Dir: D:\Code\LearningPlugins\LearningPlugins\bin\Debug 
> Assembly location: D:\Code\LearningPlugins\LearningPlugins\bin\Debug\StandalonePlugin.dll
> 
> <ENTER> to continue
```

Now for the question: Why does the AppDomain list `LearningPlugins.exe` instead of `PluginDomain`, as specified in `AppDomain pluginDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("PluginDomain", null, setup);` ?

To clarify, I don't care about vshost being added. I'm wondering why the AppDomain `PluginDomain` isn't displayed. It seems like the parent AppDomain is used even though I want to create an extra appdomain for the plugin

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202.aspx

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus: I disabled the Visual Studio Hosting process and still get LearningPlugins.exe as the AppDomain. My question is: Why isn't the PluginDomain I specifically created being used?

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the application in debug mode, vshost is added to the friendly name. 
Workaround is use the regex

```
string myName = Regex.Replace(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, 
    @"(?<basename>.*).vshost(?<extension>\..*)", "${basename}${extension}");
```

Purpose of [vshost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtemp/archive/2004/08/17/215764.aspx)
Also you can check AppDomain.FriendlyName [issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/106075/system-appdomain-currentdomain-friendlyname-returns-backward-compatibility-issue)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName`.

As explained in msdn ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.friendlyname )

> The friendly name of the default application domain is the file name
>   of the process executable

=> LearningPlugin.exe for you

So you should make something like that

in Main :

```
Console.WriteLine(plugin.Execute("Test", pluginDomain));
```

in Standalone Plugin :

```
public string Execute(string data, AppDomain childDomain)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            result.AppendFormat("Plugintype: {0}\r\n", this.GetType().FullName);
            result.AppendFormat("Data: {0}\r\n", data);
            result.AppendFormat("AppDomain: {0}\r\n", childDomain.FriendlyName);//CHANGE HERE
            result.AppendFormat("Current Dir: {0}\r\n", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
            result.AppendFormat("Assembly location: {0}\r\n", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            return result.ToString();
        }
```